# Python Numpy array assignment casting int

Tags: python, numpy, int

I'm fairly new with numpy.

As shown below, when I try to cast the numeric values from strings to integers, it doesn't seem to 'stick', as below:

```
>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([['a','1','2'],['b','3','4']])
>>> a[:,1:3].astype(int)
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
>>> a[:,1:3] = a[:,1:3].astype(int)
>>> a
array([['a', '1', '2'],
       ['b', '3', '4']],
      dtype='<U1')
```

How can I convert the string values to ints in the array ?

Comment: NumPy arrays are homogeneous, there are no mixed type arrays (except `object` arrays but these are not what I would call recommended!). So the question you need to ask yourself is: what integer value should `'a'` or `'b'` have?

Answer (score 2):

You need to first change the `dtype` of the full array to `object` in order for it to contain both strings and integers:

```
a = a.astype(object)
a[:,1:3] = a[:,1:3].astype(int)
print(a)
> [['a' 1 2]
   ['b' 3 4]]
```

Though note that better solutions may exist, for example using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/), using columns of different types.